# Number of times one row column equals another row's other column in SQL

Tags: sql

The confusing question is best asked through an example. Say we have the following result set:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qHZcfBD.png]

What I want to do is count how many times one number appears from both columns.

So the returning data set might look like:

```
ID    Counted
0      4
1      2
9      1
13     1
```

My original thought was to do some sort of addition between the counts on both IDs, but I'm not exactly sure how to `GROUP` them in SQL in a way that is working.

Comment: It would be better if you pasted the text instead of an image. It's small enough that you can re-type it.

Comment: how is this result set generated? paste your sql pls

Comment: @Apostolos There are four zeros (top row), two ones (second row), one nine (third row), and one thirteen (bottom row) among the combined values of `ID1` and `ID2`.

Comment: yes i got that but the thing is which is the source query that returns the results of posted image so as to help him. your answer is obvious but does he select the ids from the same table as you posted via union?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery, `GROUP BY`, and a `UNION ALL`, like this:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*)
FROM(
    SELECT ID1 AS ID FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
    SELECT ID2 AS ID FROM MyTable
) source
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: Ah, was unaware of the UNION ALL call. Works perfect, thank you.